# How can I override the configuration such as Load Balancer and Capacity for my ElasticBeanstalk application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to deploy a sample PHP application on the ElasticBeanstalk using CloudFormation as an attempt to learn the CloudFormation.

The following is my template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: AWS CloudFormation Sample PHP Application on ElasticBeanstalk Template
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the AWS Elastic
      Beanstalk instance
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    ConstraintDescription: must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
Mappings:
  Region2Principal:
    us-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-south-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-east-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ca-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    sa-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    cn-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    cn-northwest-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    eu-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
Resources:
  WebServerRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - Fn::FindInMap:
                    - Region2Principal
                    - Ref: AWS::Region
                    - EC2Principal
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
  WebServerRolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: WebServerRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            NotAction: iam:*
            Resource: '*'
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole
  WebServerInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole
  SampleApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample PHP Application
  SampleApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      Description: Version 1.0
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: SampleApplication
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket:
          Fn::Join:
            - '-'
            - - elasticbeanstalk-samples
              - Ref: AWS::Region
        S3Key: php-sample.zip
  SampleConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: SampleApplication
      Description: SSH access to PHP Application
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.3 running PHP 7.3
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: EC2KeyName
          Value:
            Ref: KeyName
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          Value:
            Ref: WebServerInstanceProfile
  SampleEnvironment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Sample PHP Application
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: SampleApplication
      EnvironmentName: LaravelAppTesting
      TemplateName:
        Ref: SampleConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: SampleApplicationVersion
Outputs:
  URL:
    Description: URL of the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment
    Value:
      Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - http://
          - Fn::GetAtt:
              - SampleEnvironment
              - EndpointURL
```

As you can see below, the ElasticBeanstalk has configurations such as Load Balancer, Capacity and so on. Now, I am trying to override, Load Balancer settings of Beanstalk. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some properties can be modified by adding [OptionSettings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html#cfn-beanstalk-environment-optionsettings) to your `SampleEnvironment` resource in CloudFormation. A list of these options are available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html).

For other scenarios you should look at [configuring the environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html) by using [ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) inside your deployed application.

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks again for the answer. But I am still not very clear how I to use them, the OptionSettings. I checked the list of available options. For example, aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration. What does that namespace do? We can define option, IamInstanceProfile. What is that and where can I see the doc for that? What are the values we can set to those options? Can you please explain and point me out to the right direction?

Comment: The documentation is limited to listing the options in the link in the answer, most of these options would require a bit of research, for example the IamInstanceProfile is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html. The values will most likely match their CloudFormation resource counterpart i.e. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-instanceprofile.html

Comment: Hi @Chris Williams. Thanks a lot. The documentation should be more organised in this area. The reason I would like to use CloudFormation is that I want the infrastructure to be more organised and also save time. The research would also require an experienced developer too. It seems like it is adding a lot more extra workload than expected to enjoy the fruits. Thanks again.